# How to get a full command list of the Cardano-cli

Tags: cardano-cli

I'm trying to fix something (the cardanocli-js) that broke with this last update (1.31.0) but i don't know how to see the correct way that, in 1.31.0 version, the Cli make transactions (or find how much cost the fee). I didn't find the list of commands and their correct use..

I know that using help i can somewhat get it. But there is a more explanatory version somewhere?

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only one I know is this:

- [Cardano Node CLI Reference](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/reference/cardano-node-cli-reference.md)
- [EDIT] [Create Simple Transaction](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/stake-pool-course/handbook/create-simple-transaction) (although it's a bit outdated) this one explains very well how to create a transaction and calculate fees.

Related to fee, first you need to build the transaction then you can use this command:

```
cardano-cli transaction calculate-min-fee \
  --tx-body-file transaction.raw \
  --tx-in-count 1 \
  --tx-out-count 1 \
  --witness-count 2 \
  --testnet-magic 1097911063 \
  --protocol-params-file protocol-params.json
```

Where:

> --tx-body-file FILE      Input filepath of the JSON TxBody.
>
> --tx-in-count NATURAL    The number of transaction inputs.
>
> --tx-out-count NATURAL   The number of transaction outputs.
>
> --witness-count NATURAL  The number of Shelley key witnesses.

There is a [good explanation to calculate fees](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/4371/1231)