# Back-to-back transactions produce ValueNotConservedUTxO error

Tags: cardano-cli, transaction

I recently wrote some scripts that mint and send tokens. When I run the script to mint a token and then immediately run the script to send that token to a wallet, I get this error:

```
Error: Command failed: cardano-cli transaction submit --testnet-magic 1097911063 --tx-file ./tmp/tx_n5sm4btig.signed
Command failed: transaction submit  Error: Error while submitting tx: ShelleyTxValidationErrorShelleyBasedEraAlonzo (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (ValueNotConservedUTxO (Value 0 (fromList [(PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash "1a1b09e939ec7fd1b60c1e4d71808926421079f679e79d1e9f36561a"},fromList [("TestNFT",1)])])) (Value 992262587 (fromList [(PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash "1a1b09e939ec7fd1b60c1e4d71808926421079f679e79d1e9f36561a"},fromList [("TestNFT",1)]),(PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash "584af528f36789c8d5cc9336ec258326cbea8b3983d9d6d40cdc5bce"},fromList [("TestNFT",1)]),(PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash "6eee44f15e11b84d33bcaaff8096d36fa400f6cb8eaa14007d6fac1b"},fromList [("TestNFT",1)]),(PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash "b294451d861bc02b49591d9413a12f8b24a0f17c57940c9d78d1074c"},fromList [("TestNFT",1)]),(PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash "e7ba14bfcb30f171b106ea15984cd25101d73f72fc89f2bb864ff600"},fromList [("TestNFT",1)])]))))),UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (BadInputsUTxO (fromList [TxIn (TxId {_unTxId = SafeHash "7d667aef6319a22a71903fca4d88b69cea24e23c36120e11f34738aa8d90da07"}) 0]))))])
```

A similar error happens if I run the script to mint a token and then immediately re-run it. It seems like rapid back-to-back transactions cause this. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Edit: I wanted to add that the scripts work as expected if there is a pause (>~1 minute) between each execution.

Any help is appreciated, and I apologize if this is a basic question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the error `ValueNotConservedUTxO` means that your transaction is not balanced. Take a look on this [answer](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/4371/1231) to follow the appropiate process to submit transactions.

Other points to consider:

1. Depending how you're building and submitting your transactions, but consider that your transactions need to be confirmed in order to get your UTxOs updated.
2. > When I run the script to mint a token and then immediately run the script to send that token to a wallet, I get this error

- You can't mint a NFT and send it immediately in another transaction because you need to wait until the first transaction (your NFT) get reflected on your UTxOs
- But you can mint and send the NFT in the same transaction. I think this is the best approach.

```
    cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
    --fee <fee> \
    --tx-in <tx_in> \
    --tx-out <your_address>+<change> \
    --tx-out <destination_address>+<minUtxO>+1 <nft> \
    --mint=1 <nft> \
    --minting-script-file <policy-file> \
    --metadata-json-file <metadata-file> \
    --invalid-hereafter=<slot> \
    --out-file <outputfile.raw>
```

3. > A similar error happens if I run the script to mint a token and then immediately re-run it.

- Consider that your UTxOs  get re ordered every time you submit a transaction.

Comment: This was very helpful; thank you. The problem was related to UTxOs not being updated, as you said. I'll attempt to mint and send in the same transaction and see how it goes.