# How to send a native token using the cardano-cli?

Tags: cardano-cli, token

What are the steps required to build and send a transaction meant to send for example 10,000 tokens to some given address?

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a good explanation](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/4371/1231) of the process to build and submit a transaction.

In your case, your `build-raw` command should be similar to this:

```
cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
    --fee <fee> \
    --tx-in <tx_in> \
    --tx-out <your_address>+<change> \
    --tx-out <destination_address>+<minUtxO>+10000 <Tokens> \
    --mint=10000 <Tokens> \
    --minting-script-file <policy-file> \
    --invalid-hereafter=<slot> \
    --out-file <outputfile.raw>
```

Answer (score 1):

This script can be useful for you https://github.com/invictusappscom/cardano-terminal-wallet/blob/e07119c6130adc36512f30bb554518784e177dc7/send-token.sh

For more info check point 6 at README.md https://github.com/invictusappscom/cardano-terminal-wallet/blob/master/README.md